# How to call api path in thymeleaf to reload table data in javascript function

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

I need click the submit button to reload table data,
But in javascript function , I don't known how to call the url pass parameters in thymeleaf.
I call this web page is below:

```
 .....[menu partial code]....
      <a class="dropdown-item" th:href="@{/registeredUserList(type=0,userId=id0001,page=0,size=10)}">user list</a>
 .....
```

the query and content Page:

```
 <form >
                        <div class="col-sm-3 my-1">
                                <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputName">Name</label> <input
                                    type="text" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputName"
                                    placeholder="user name">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-auto my-1">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary query-submit"
                                    id="querySubmit">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>

 .....
        <div class="row mt-5" th:fragment="table_content">
            <div class="col">
      ...
              <table class="table table-responsive table-hover">
                <tbody>
                           <tr th:each="users,iter : ${response.content}">
                                <th scope="row" th:text="${iter.index+1}"></th>
                            <td class="text-info text-center"
                                th:text="${users.name}"></td>
                           </tr>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
          </div>
   </div>
 .....
```

I don't know the syntax in thymeleaf , if I need pass the params and call api in the js function. If the url will write @{/registeredUserList(type=0,userId=id0001,page=0,size=10)} like menu path, how can I write the syntax in the js function at url.
thank you~

```
 $(function() {
        $('#querySubmit').click(querySubmitClickAction);
        querySubmit.addEventListener('click', querySubmitClickAction);
        function querySubmitClickAction(e) {
            
            $.ajax({
                url: url, // here , I don't know syntax, I can't use [@{/registeredUserList(type=0,userId=id0001,page=0,size=10)}] the path in here . how can I write the syntax.
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {
                    $(".table_content").html(data);
                }
            })
         }
      });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `th:inline="javascript"` and the `/*[[@{/url/}]]*/` syntax:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
$(function() {
        $('#querySubmit').click(querySubmitClickAction);
        querySubmit.addEventListener('click', querySubmitClickAction);
        function querySubmitClickAction(e) {
            
            $.ajax({
                url: /*[[@{/registeredUserList(type=0,userId=id0001,page=0,size=10)}]]*/ 'dummy',
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {
                    $(".table_content").html(data);
                }
            })
         }
      });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you response for me, further a question, If in js function , I declare the var theSize = 10; variable . How to (theSize variable) bring in the  url: /*[[@{/registeredUserList(type=0,userId=id0001,page=0,size=10)}]]*? Thank you very much. @Wim Deblauwe

Comment: Not sure. Maybe you can put the url also in a JavaScript variable and use string replacement or something to manipulate the URL. Maybe ask a separate question for this so others can answer that particular point?

Comment: Thank you. I ask a separate question in the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68030499/how-can-i-put-the-variable-in-the-inline-javascript-api-path