# How can I put the variable in the inline javascript [[]] api path

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

I have a question, I need make up the url in the javasctipt.
But I don't known how to put the variable in the th:inline="javascript" .
My code below:

```
 <script th:inline="javascript">
 $(function() {
    $('#querySubmit').click(querySubmitClickAction);
    querySubmit.addEventListener('click', querySubmitClickAction);
    function querySubmitClickAction(e) {
        
        var theSize = 10;
        var name = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: /* 
[[@{/registeredUserList(type=0,userName=defaultName,page=0,size=10)}]]*/ 'dummy',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                $(".table_content").html(data);
            }
        })
     }
  });
```

How can I make up the url using the variable in the [[]].

```
 url: /*[[@{/registeredUserList(type=0,userName=name,page=0,size=theSize)}]]*/ 'will show error',
```

It's will show error. How can I use the js variable put in the [[]].

Thank you very much.

Comment: can you share with us the end url you want?

Comment: My url will put this, it's will call the api. url: @{/registeredUserList(type=0,userName=typeName,page=0,size=10)}

Comment: I'm using springboot, so the registeredUserList will call my controller and pass type,userName,page and size parameters .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/

    // JavaScript variable
    var theSize = 10;

    // URL from Thymeleaf, note the round brackets to avoid that / becomes \/
    var theUrl = "[(@{/users/})]";

    // Create an URL object resolving the relative url
    var url = new URL(theUrl, document.location);

    // Update the query parameters of the URL with the JavaScript variables
    url.searchParams.append("size", theSize);

    console.log(url);

    /*]]>*/
</script>
```

In the JavaScript console, this prints:

> http://localhost:3000/users/?size=10